# Why is @ID variable being rendered differently inside the same <text></text> element

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to automatically generate some javascript, a line for each row in my data model, which requires the ID value on each row to be inserted into the javascript.

This is the code inside the script element on the HTML page:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    var ID = item.QuestionID;
    <text>$('#toggle-off@ID-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-@ID').show(); })</text>
}
        });
    </script>
```

The output is:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
    $('#toggle-off@ID-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-1').show(); })
    $('#toggle-off@ID-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-2').show(); })
    $('#toggle-off@ID-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-3').show(); })
...
```

When I would have expected it to be:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
    $('#toggle-off1-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-1').show(); })
    $('#toggle-off2-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-2').show(); })
    $('#toggle-off3-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-3').show(); })
...
```

Comment: Why do you need to generate separate `click` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the razor engine considers `@ID` as part of the string if it is preceded by an alphanumeric character. If you add an hyphen before it works correctly: `#toggle-off-@ID-label`. You can surround `ID` with parentheses to get your expected output:

```
  <script>
        $(function () {
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                var ID = item.QuestionID;
                <text>$('#toggle-off@(ID)-label').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-@ID').show(); })</text>
            }
        });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Razor markup parser isn't that bright and considers `off@ID` to be a single token and so not something that it should replace.

You should be able get around it with something like this:

```cs
    <script>
        $(function () {
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    var ID = item.QuestionID;
    var toggle = string.format("#toggle-off{0}-label", ID);
    <text>$('@toggle').click(function() { $('#Question-Answer-@ID').show(); })</text>
}
        });
    </script>
```